# Is there a way to take the printed numbers and turn it into an Array in java?

Tags: java, arrays, printing

I have written the following code to remove duplicates from an inputted array. However, the numbers outputted is not in an array. They are just numbers printed next to each other. Is there a way to get these numbers into an array and then to print the array instead?

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class removeDuplicates { 
   
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      
      int[] array = input();
      
      System.out.println("Orginal Array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
      
      removeDuplicates(array);
      
      
     } 
     
     // method to take input into an array 
     public static int[] input() { 
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      
      System.out.println("Enter the amount of elements you would like to have: ");
      int size = input.nextInt();
      
      int[] array = new int[size];
      
      System.out.println("Enter the " + size + " elements you would like to include: ");
      for (int i = 0;i < size; i++) {
         array[i] = input.nextInt();
         
      
      
      }
      
      return array;

     }
     

public static void removeDuplicates(int[] array) {

   HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
   int n = array.length;
   
      for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
         if(map.containsKey(array[i])) { 
            map.put(array[i], map.get(array[i]) + 1);
           
           } else {
            map.put(array[i], 1);
            
            }
          }
         map.forEach((k, v)-> System.out.print(k + " " ));
       }
     }
```

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 1):

something like that?

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> removeDuplicates(int[] array) {

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();  // Array List added
        int n = array.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            if(map.containsKey(array[i])) {
                map.put(array[i], map.get(array[i]) + 1);

            } else {
                map.put(array[i], 1);

            }
        }
        map.forEach((k, v)-> System.out.print(k + " " ));
        map.forEach((k, v)->arr.add(k)); // add each element to ArrayList
        
        return arr; 
    }
```

Comment: I get the following error when running this: Main.java:17: error: cannot find symbol
public static ArrayList<Integer> removeDuplicates(int[] array) {

Comment: Did you add import java.utils.ArrayList? Because it should work... ofc you have to print it out later elsewhere